# Protecting the database against bad queries

Tags: database

I want to build a clustered and/or replicated relational database so that all of the company's apps can use the same data without manually shuffling it between databases.

However, this raises two issues:

- A bad update or delete query can disable all apps and services
- If all storage is unified, how do we handle staging?

My thoughts on this is that something like transaction-based version control for data (like git for source) could be useful, but in general I could use any idea on how to mitigate these issues.

Answer (score 3):

> A bad update or delete query can disable all apps and services

- With great power comes great responsibility. Fine-grain the database
  user permissions and make sure that only the users that understand
  that have the power.
- Use sandbox systems, do not do development on production.
- Have a way to rollback changes / restore database at hand. Test it.

> If all storage is unified, how do we handle staging?

Like you say, use versioning. Application code versioning [e.g. svn] and you might also try database versioning [ and e.g.  Jenkins for deployment].

Comment: What if the worst happened? Can I configure a database to allow for (maybe limited) undoing of transactions?

Comment: yes, it is possible, depending on your database flavour, look for `transaction rollback`.  In Oracle for example, you `alter database archivelog` and all the redo logs [files that hold the changes to the database] will be archived instead of being overwritten allowing you to go for point in time recovery for example.

Comment: Is there a database engine that specifically features such a system? I'm especially interested in forking and merging database versions